# How to find about individual votes of Members of European Parliament?

Tags: european-parliament, reference-request

I want to find individual votes record who was for/against on this resolution, how to do it?

http://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/TA-9-2019-0101_EN.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of votes are usually found here: https://www.europarl.europa.eu/plenary/en/votes.html?tab=votes

Votes taken specifically on the 18th can be found here: https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2019-12-18-RCV_FR.pdf

Comment: Just make sure I'm doing it right - the declaration is filed under B9-0234/2019 thus the votes are in PDF on pages 11-35, where on page 35 is final voting on whole resolution?

Comment: Page 35 will be the final vote on the resolution, including any amendments that had been approved in the previous votes.